# Calculating based on 3 last entries

Tags: sql

I have a table with data (Client name, date, result):

```
client,date,result
A,9/19/2019,0
A,9/20/2019,0
A,9/21/2019,0
A,9/22/2019,0.2
B,9/9/2019,0
B,9/10/2019,0
B,9/11/2019,0.3
B,9/12/2019,0.5
```

And I would like to count number of client when client has 0 as a result for the previous 3 weeks. 
So the output would be:

```
 date, noOfUsers
 9/22/2019, 1
```

No idea what to start from.

Comment: `last 3 entries` is totally different than `previous 3 weeks`. Which is it?

Comment: I meant last 3 weeks. Lets assume this table is already sorted.

Comment: Tables are **never** sorted in a SQL database, remember?

Comment: `Select Count(Distinct client) usercount From table where date between 'week 1' and getdate() having SUM(result) = 0.` Something like this... I'm SQL Server, but not sure what your RDBMS is.